# access label inside a repeater ItemTemplate that is inside a usercontrol from asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater inside a user control.User control in on page shoppingcart.aspx.I want to access all lblPrice from javascript from a function inside shoppingcart.aspx.How to access all of these labels.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptShoppingCart" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <tr class="big_header_style">
            <td>
                Product(s)
            </td>
            <td>
                Description</td>
            <td>
                Quantity</td>
            <td>
                Price (INR)</td>
            <td>
                Total (INR)</td>
            <td>
                Remove?</td>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="dg_item_style">
            <td align="center">
                <img src='<%# Page.ResolveUrl(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ProductInfo.thumbnailPath1")))%>'
                    width="90" height="90" /></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ProductInfo.productName") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td align="center">
                <input id="proQuantity" runat="server" type="text" size="1" value='<%#Eval("Quantity") %>' /></td>
            <td align="center">
                <strong class="redtxt">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#GetPrice((BAL.ShoppingCartMaster)Container.DataItem)%>' /></strong></td>
            <td align="center">
                <strong class="redtxt">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text='<%#calculatePrice((BAL.ShoppingCartMaster)Container.DataItem)%>'></asp:Label></strong>
            </td>                                                                                        
            <td align="center">
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbRemoveFromCart" />
                <asp:Label id="lblShoppingCartID" runat="server" visible="false" text='<%#Eval("ShoppingCartID") %>'></asp:Label>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you take the clientID of your user control:

```
var userControlId = '<%= ShoppingCart1.ClientID %>';
```

Then, you can build on that the clientID of the repeater:

```
var repeaterId = userControlId + '_rptShoppingCart';
```

And then you can access all the labels lblPrice inside the repeater, like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var rowNo = i;
    if (rowNo < 10)
        rowNo = "0" + rowNo;

    var lblPrice = document.getElementById(repeaterId + '_ctl' + rowNo + '_lblPrice');

    if (lblPrice != undefined)
        lblPrice.innerHTML = i * 10;
}
```

It looks a bit hacky, and it actually is a bit hacky, but it does the thing and, if you have no other option, it sure does help. And also, it's really fast, if you have a lot of elements.

That "for" going to 500 can be made nicer, but it's more code and I wanted to keep the answer short.

Answer (score -1):

It would be very easy for you if you are using jquery. Please check the below example for accessing asp.net controls on Master Page. You can check original article [here.](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/07/access-aspnet-control-on-masterpage.html)

You can also use ClientId property of control in Java script.

```
document.getElementById("<%=txtFirstName.ClientID %>");
```

But the problem with above approach is you have to make the Javascript inline and it can not be external.

```
MasterPage

<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Access Control using jQuery</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("input[id$='_txtName']").val("Text Added using jQuery");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>




ContentPage

<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"

AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MasterPage"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"

Runat="Server">

<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: sorry not using jquery and not using master page.

Comment: then you can use ClientId property.

Comment: No, you can't use ClientID for controls inside a Repeater.